# AutoResetEvent() in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrency

I have three two classes

```
Class A{
   function A.1()
   {
     1. First calls B.2()
     2. Checks for value X in class B.
   }
}
Class B {
 function B.1()
 {
  /*this function sets the variable X to true*/
 }
 function B.2()
 {
   /*Initiates the thread eventually that will start the function B.1 on different thread*/
 }
}
```

I want to modify this so that, A.1() should wait until X is set/modified in Class B. This is what my approach is:

```
Class A{
   function A.1()
   {
     1. First calls B.2()
     **2. Call WaitforSet in class B**
     3. Checks for value X in class B.
   }
}
Class B {
/* Created one autoreset event S*/
 function B.1()
 {
  /*this function sets the variable X to true*/
  S.Set();
 }
 function B.2()
 {
   /*Initiates the thread eventually that will start the function B.1 on different thread*/
 }
  waitforSet()
  {
   S.waitone();
  }
}
```

I am not sure why this is not working, as it puts both the thread on wait. I expected `waitforSet()` function should have put calling thread on wait and internal will continue setting X. When i checked the currentthread's managed thread id in `waitforSet()` and `B.1()` they are different.

Can someone tell me what i am missing here or better way to achieve this?

P.S: I am achieving this in C#

Comment: Please provide real code.
In general Class A should not know the internals of class B, so there should be no traces of synchronisation in Class A.
The easiest for you would be to use locking with Monitor.Wait() and Monitor.Pulse() inside the getter and setter methods of the variable X.

Comment: Thank you for the response, however i would like to know what i missing in my approach. I understand this example violates lot of OOPs principle. I found lot of approaches for Fast producer and slow consumer however this is more of Slow producer and Fast Consumer problem.

Thank you

Comment: Have you considered using the TPL http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I created this and it working normally, are you sure you are setting the initial state of AutoResetEvent to false in the constructor ?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Thread.CurrentThread.Name = "Console Thread";

        var a = new A();
        a.A1();

        Console.WriteLine("Press return to exit...");
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public void A1()
    {
        var b = new B();

        b.B2();
        b.WaitForSet();

        Console.WriteLine("Signal received by " +  Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " should be ok to check value of X");
        Console.WriteLine("Value of X = " + b.X);
    }
}

public class B
{
    private AutoResetEvent S = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public bool X { get; private set; } 

    public void B1()
    {
        X = true;
        Console.WriteLine("X set to true by " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);

        S.Set();
        Console.WriteLine("Release the hounds signal by " + Thread.CurrentThread.Name);
    }

    public void B2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B2 starting thread...");

        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(B1)) { Name = "B Thread" };
        thread.Start();

        Console.WriteLine("Value of X = " + X + " Thread started.");
    }

    public void WaitForSet()
    {
        S.WaitOne();
        Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.Name + " Waiting one...");
    }
}
```